# Windows store app custom gestures

Tags: windows-store-apps

I would like to teach my application (Windows Store application) to recognize custom gestures like triangles, ellipses, squares and etc. I found one [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) similar to what I'm looking for, but it's not for windows store applications. I'm curious if there is any api available to do this task or it should be implemented in a "Do It Yourself" manner?